# Word count in Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides

I have a presentation on Google Slides and I'd like to find the word count of all the words (or even just space delimited sections of text).

It doesn't appear that there is any straight-forward way to do this, but surely there must be some way/hack to find this information out approximately.

Comment: You can export as a text file, IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

Download slide as txt file.  Open, select all text, copy to a clipboard.  Go to [wordcounter.net](https://wordcounter.net/) and paste the text in there. :)